# A question about the image of a complex continues function under close sets

Tags: complex-analysis

In page 62, line -9 (in the first Edition) of Ahlfors "Complex Analysis" it is written that

**"The image of an open set under a continues mapping is not always open, nor is the image of a closed set always closed."**

I can agree with the first comment since the function $f(z)=|z|$ is clearly continues in $\mathbb C$, but $f(\mathbb C)=\mathbb R$ is not open. I have a problem with the second comment. In Theorem 8 (page 8) Ahlfors proves that

**Theorem 8: Under a continues mapping the image of every compact set is compact**

Now, suppose that $A\subseteq\mathbb C$ is a close set and $f:A\to\mathbb C$ is a continues function on $A$.

If $A$ is in addition bounded, then $A$ is compact, so $f(A)$ is compact and in particular is closed.

If $A$ is not bounded, then by Ahlfors definition, $A$ is compact (By page 60, lane 4: "In the extended plane any closed set is called compact."), so $f(A)$ is compact and in particular is closed.

Which contradicts Alfors second comment.

Does Theorem 8 of Ahlfors regard only "ordinary" complex plane and not the extended plane ? Is there an example of a continues function $f$ on a closed set $A$ such that $f(A)$ is not closed - even in the extended plain?

Comment: Note that are planning to apply Theorem 8 to a set that is going to become compact on the extended plane. To do that you need $f$ to extend to a continuous function on the extended plane. That might not be the case for $f$. Even if it were, the set to which you apply the theorem might be a new set, $A\cup\{\infty\}$.

Comment: With example. Consider $f(z)=e^z$ and $A=(1+i)\mathbb{R}$. Here $f$ doesn't have limit as $z\to\infty$. So, we can't apply Theorem 8, to a continuous extension of $f$. Consider $f(z)=e^{|z|}$. This time $f$ has a continuous extension by putting $f(\infty)=\infty$. We would apply Theorem 8 with $A\cup\{\infty\}$, which has image $\{r\in\mathbb{R}\mid 1\leq r\}\cup\{\infty\}$. This is compact in the extended plane, but the image of the original set is the same with the point $\infty$ removed. It is not compact.

Comment: Thanks @plop, but when $f$ is continues on a $A\cup\{\infty\}$, what is the definition for that situation ? I could not find any clear definition for continuity in the extended plain.

Comment: Is it true that $f$ is continues in $\infty$ if $\lim_{z\to\infty}f(z)$ exists ?

Comment: If it exists and is equal to $f(\infty)$. If $f$ hasn't been defined at $z=\infty$, then the existence of that limit says that there is some continuous extension, exactly by defining $f(\infty)$ to be the value of that limit.

Comment: I see...thanks ! you have helped me a lot

Comment: By the way, we need to consider $\lim_{z\to\infty}f(z)=\infty$ as a limit that exists.